# Crashing Activity when button clicked in Android studio

Tags: android

need some help with android. I'm new to android development so please bear with me.

I have two activity and I am able to successfully go to the second activity by a button click event(intent), however once I click a button in the second activity, the activity crashes and goes back to the main activity.

here is my codes:

```
 public  boolean insertEmployee(String name, int pin, int roleid)
    {
        mydb= getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentvalue= new ContentValues();`enter code here`
        contentvalue.put(emp_name, name);
        contentvalue.put(emp_Pin,pin);
        contentvalue.put(emp_roleID,roleid);
        long result=mydb.insert(emp,null,contentvalue);
        if(result==-1)
            return  false;
        else
            return  true;


    }
```

and on my secondactivity.java

```
public void insertEmployee()
    {
        btnemployee.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        boolean isSuccess = dbhelp.insertEmployee(name.getText().toString(), Integer.parseInt(pin.getText().toString()), Integer.parseInt(roleid.getText().toString()));


                    }
                }
        );
    }
```

and manifest.xml

```
<activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity2Activity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

        </activity>
```

Just can't seems to understand but if I have only one activity the insert method works.
Please help. Thanks guys

LOgcat

```
  06-29 16:07:29.125  15133-15133/
 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: "I REMOVED APP NAME", PID: 15133
        java.lang.NullPointerException
                at 
.MainActivity2Activity$1.onClick(MainActivity2Activity.java:45)
                at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
                at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18439)
                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5095)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

XML

```
 <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Insert Employee"
        android:id="@+id/binsertEmployee"
        android:layout_below="@+id/bRoleinsert"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/bRoleinsert"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/bRoleinsert" />
```

mainactivity2.java

```
public class MainActivity2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
    DatabaseHelper dbhelp;
    Button btnemployee, btnrole;
    EditText role,name,pin,roleid;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity2);
        btnrole=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bRoleinsert);
        btnemployee=(Button)findViewById(R.id.binsertEmployee);
        role=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        name=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        pin=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText4);
        roleid=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText5);

        InsertRole();
        insertEmployee();
    }
```

Comment: please post error log

Comment: *`Crashing Activity when button clicked`* Where is you crash log? your need to share that crash report

Comment: please send all code and also error log

Comment: `Logcat` and `Debugging` are 2 best friends of Android developer.

Comment: I think ur running in main thread!!!

Comment: Are you sure `btnemployee` isn't null?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    btnemployee.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                   dbhelp.insertEmployee(name.getText().toString(), Integer.parseInt(pin.getText().toString()), Integer.parseInt(roleid.getText().toString()));


                }
            }
    );
```

Comment: Explain your changes

Answer (score 0):

You have a NullPointerException error at your btnemployee, which means that the button was never initalized.  You may have made it a global variable with `Button btnemployee`, but you may have not actually assigned it to the button in your XML file.  Assuming for example that your button in the XML has an id of btnEmployee, you would need to assign it like this in your `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` method:

`btnemployee = findViewById(R.id.btnEmployee)`

Make sure that your button in your layout has an id assigned, like:

`android:id="@+id/btnEmployee"`

With that, the resource will be available to your code, in the form of `R.id.btnEmployee`.

While you must make sure to assign the value in the onCreate method, you must not declare the variable there, or it will be in the scope of the onCreate method only.  Instead you have to be sure to declare the type in the class scope.